# semantic ui scrolling dropdown doesn't show the selected item

Tags: javascript, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm using a semantic ui scrolling dropdown.

On page load I set the selected value.

The problem is when we open the dropdown by default semantic-ui shows the firsts elements of the dropdown and doesn't show the selected value.

If you select another value, then, the new dropdown position is the one of the selected value.

Is there a way to show the selected element when the dropdown is opened the first time.

Dropdown

```js
$('.dropdown').dropdown();
$('.dropdown').dropdown( 'set selected', '10');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui scrolling dropdown">
  <div class="text">10</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" data-value="1">1</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="2">2</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="3">3</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="4">4</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="5">5</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="6">6</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="7">7</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="8">8</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="9">9</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="10">10</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I solved using .index() and .scrollTop() and the dropdown callback .onShow

```js
$('.dropdown').dropdown();
$('.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', '10');
$('.dropdown').dropdown({
  onShow: function(value, text) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var preSelected = $('#dd > div.item.active.selected').index('.item');
      $('#dd').scrollTop((preSelected - 2) * 36);
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui scrolling dropdown">
  <div class="text">10</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu" id="dd">
    <div class="item" data-value="1">1</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="2">2</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="3">3</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="4">4</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="5">5</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="6">6</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="7">7</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="8">8</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="9">9</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="10">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```